# URLComponents init fails

Tags: ios, swift, urlcomponents

I'm trying to create an `URLComponents` object so I can extract parameters values from a string. I have the string `topic_id12&lessong_id=45`:

```
let dataString = "topic_id12&lessong_id=45"
guard let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://somedomain.com/\(dataString)/") else return { nil }
```

However the init fails. Any ideas what I'm missing here? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean by fail (it does not return nil). What is the expected result for your URL ? the example above would result in [https://somedomain.com/topic_id12&lessong_id=45/](https://somedomain.com/topic_id12&lessong_id=45/)

Answer (score -2):

You can safely remove `guard` and `else return { nil }` part from your code.

Comment: This is wrong since the init is declared as optional